# Selecting rows which does not have particular values against the values of another column

Tags: sql-server

My query is like:

I have a table Table1

```
     SkillID            EmpCode
    ------------------------------
    2                   A101
    4                   A101
    5                   A101
    8                   A101
    4                   A102
    3                   A102
    1                   A102
    6                   A102
    5                   A102
    7                   A102
```

Now I have to SELECT EmpCode which does not have SkillIDs 1, 6, & 7.
Here in the example it should give EmpCode **A101** as the result.
**Only EmpCodes which doesn't include SkillID 1, 6 & 7 should be the result**

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT EmpCode
FROM mytable
GROUP BY EmpCode
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN SkillID IN (1, 6, 7) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b5bc)

You can alternatively use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpCode
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM mytable AS t2
  WHERE t1.EmpCode = t2.EmpCode AND t2.SkillID IN (1, 6, 7) )
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b5bc/3)

Answer (score 2):

the code below is in t-sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpCode
FROM Table1
WHERE SkillID NOT IN (1, 6, 7)
```